# How do I show only numbers from a Javascript array that has both numbers and letters use parseInt?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

I'm trying to use the parseInt to show only numbers from the following array:

```
1,2,a,b
```

Here is my javascript code so far:

```
var filter_list = ["1,2,a,b"];

function myFunction() {
  parseInt(filter_list);
  return filter_list;
}

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = filter_list;
```

Maybe my idea isn't even going to work. Would love some feedback.

Comment: It seems like your missing some foundational knowledge of JavaScript here. You haven't got an array of four items, you have a single item array containing a string. You define a function (`myFunction`) but don't invoke it anywhere, and that function uses `parseInt` but doesn't consume the return value. You should probably start with a JavaScript tutorial that covers some of these basic concepts, there are some good ones on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: You need to call parseInt for every element, not for the whole array. Then you can filter for NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have array with one element that is string, so you could use `join` and `split` and then `filter` method.

```js
var data = ["1,2,a,b"];
var numbers = data.join(",").split(",").filter(Number);
console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: Why the `.join(",")`?

Comment: In case there are more elements like this https://jsfiddle.net/bLygnwe6/

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know that each element of the array has to have teir own " ". Like that:

```
var filter_list = ["1","2","a","b"];
```

then, if you want to know the elements that are numbres, you can do something like that:

```
var filter_list = ["1","2","a","b"];

for(i = 0; i < filter_list.length; i++ {

    if (!isNaN(ParseInt(filter_list[i])){

       var new_array = [];

       new_array[i] = filter_list[i];
    }
}

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = new_array;
```

I don't know if is that what you wanted to know.